# Can I use just Database in IdentityServer4 instead of writing all clients in Config.cs

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have been searching for how IdentityServer4 uses DB. I have read: https://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/8_entity_framework.html and looked at the QuickStart4 which uses a DB store. What I can't find is how I can use it in a many clients scenario where we want to add client details to DB only without having to add the client to the config.cs in Identity Server like so:

```
public static class Config
{
    public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> IdentityResources =>
        new List<IdentityResource>
        {
            new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
            new IdentityResources.Profile(),
        };


    public static IEnumerable<ApiScope> ApiScopes =>
        new List<ApiScope>
        {
            new ApiScope("api1", "My API")
        };

    public static IEnumerable<Client> Clients =>
        new List<Client>
        {
            // machine to machine client
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "client",
                ClientSecrets = { new Secret("secret".Sha256()) },

                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,
                // scopes that client has access to
                AllowedScopes = { "api1" }
            },
            
            // interactive ASP.NET Core MVC client
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "mvc",
                ClientSecrets = { new Secret("secret".Sha256()) },

                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
                
                // where to redirect to after login
                RedirectUris = { "https://localhost:5002/signin-oidc" },

                // where to redirect to after logout
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "https://localhost:5002/signout-callback-oidc" },

                AllowedScopes = new List<string>
                {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    "api1"
                }
            }
        };
}
```

}

Comment: Check this out https://youtu.be/Sw1rScI20xM

Comment: @Qudus I have seen it but my scenario is a machine to machine authentication where users aren't involved. It's several API clients that will authenticate with their own certificates.

Answer (score 2):

see this page [Entity Framework Integration](https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v5/data/ef/) and this page [Entity Framework Support](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/ef.html)

Basically, what you need to do is:

1. Add this NuGet package IdentityServer4.EntityFramework
2. Apply the migrations to create the necessary tables or use the pre-made SQL scripts [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/main/src/EntityFramework.Storage/migrations/SqlServer/Migrations)
3. Add the AddConfigurationStore to your startup class

Alternatively, you implement your own IClientStore implementation.